# Find textblock in code to manipulate color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to find a specific control in xaml to manipulate in code to change the background.

My problem is, can't find the specific control.

I tried .FindByName(Textblock) and with visualtreehelper. Also tried to type it in code txtVeranderkleur but the system doesn't know the control because it's inside childs i guess. Didn't work all for me.

I need to find "txtVeranderkleur". So I can change the color in code.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,28" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Background="#EE2E24" CornerRadius="15,15,15,15" Width="450" Margin="15,15,15,15">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Events" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Evenementen" Style="{StaticResource subtitle}" Margin="15,15,15,15"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"  Margin="12,-15,0,12" x:Name="lbDagprogrammaInfo" SelectionChanged="lbDagprogrammaInfo_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0,0,17">
                        <Border Width="70" Height="70" BorderBrush="#EE2E24" Background="#EE2E24" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Width="70" Height="70" Text="{Binding LineTeller}" Style="{StaticResource contentRect}"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,0,0,0">
                            **<TextBlock x:Name="txtVeranderkleur" Style="{StaticResource contentText}">
                                <Run Text="{Binding LineUur}"></Run>
                                <Run Text="{Binding LineNaam}"></Run>
                            </TextBlock>**

                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Width="480" Height="80" Background="Black" Grid.Row="2">
            <Image x:Name="imgSponsor"  Source="{Binding LineSponsorFoto}"  Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindName won't work for elements inside of a DataTemplate.

If you must, you can use lbDagprogrammaInfo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex to get the ListBoxItem containing the txtVeranderkleur you want to modify and use VisualTreeHelper.GetChild to search down the visual tree for the TextBlock.

If you can logically determine the color based on data in the DataContext of each item, you could bind Background to the appropriate Property and use an IValueConverter to choose the color.

You should also look into using Visual States to change the color if you're only looking to change the color based on the ListBox functionality, such as selection.

EDIT:

Here's a snippet of what the VisualTreeHelper path would look like, though you should find a more generic approach.

```
ListBoxItem l = lbDagprogrammaInfo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
Border b = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(l, 0) as Border;
ContentControl c = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(b, 0) as ContentControl;
ContentPresenter p = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(c, 0) as ContentPresenter;
StackPanel s = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(p, 0) as StackPanel;
TextBlock t = s.FindName("txtVeranderkleur") as TextBlock;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I don't find my txtVeranderkleur with your containerfromindex or getchild. But thanks anyway

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout You have to use ContainerFromIndex to get the ListBoxItem and then perform VisualTreeHelper.GetChild numerous times to get down to the textblock. Calling GetChild on the ListBoxItem will get you a Border, calling GetChild on the Border will get you a ContentControl, and so on.